# Why is apt upgrading suggested packages while installing a package (no command line options)?

Tags: aptitude

I'm trying to understand how aptitude works. I've downloaded all dependencies of a package (afaik all, by substituting empty dpkg status file). Later after substituting back current status file of the system when installing the package I saw `apt install` tries to download a package that was listed in `suggested` when I downloaded all dependencies. Suggested is later in list of packages to be upgraded when `apt`/`apt-get` was run w/out options.

How could such thing happen? I did tests as above for some packages before and had no need for suggested, so seems it is rare occurrence. I want to understand details of this case, how can I investigate? (I've run `dpkg -s` and "suggested" one is shown as `installed`, what else?). The package name, btw is kdenlive and one of "initially" suggested is poppler-utils.

I don't want to disable upgrades completely, I just don't want to upgrade suggested ones.

```
~$ aptitude why kdenlive poppler-utils
p   kdenlive               Depends    libkf5filemetadata3 (>= 5.0.2+git20140925)
p   libkf5filemetadata3    Recommends libkf5filemetadata-bin (= 5.92.0-0ubuntu1)
p   libkf5filemetadata-bin Depends    libpoppler-qt5-1 (>= 0.46.0)              
p   libpoppler-qt5-1       Depends    libpoppler118 (= 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.2)      
p   libpoppler118          Recommends poppler-data                              
i   poppler-data           Suggests   poppler-utils
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically happens because the suggested package is already installed (as seems to be the case here) and one of the *other* upgraded packages means it needs to be upgraded too.

For `poppler-utils`, this can happen if the corresponding `libpoppler` package is upgraded: `poppler-utils` has a strong dependency on the same version of `libpoppler`. Thus, if `libpoppler` (`libpoppler102` in Debian 11, `libpoppler126` in Debian 12) is upgraded, `poppler-utils` has to be upgraded alongside it.

To investigate this, look at `aptitude why kdenlive poppler-utils` and `apt show poppler-utils`. It might help to run `apt upgrade` with `-oDebug::pkgProblemResolver=yes` (this might explain why `poppler-utils` is added to the upgrade set).

Bear in mind that weak dependencies (“Recommends” and “Suggests”) only determine what happens when packages are installed and removed. Once a package is installed, it has to be managed like all other installed packages; it isn’t necessarily possible to upgrade “suggested” packages later — the fact that they’re only suggested no longer matters.

Comment: `aptitude why` is new command to me, thanks. I've added its output to the question. at the end `Suggests   poppler-utils`. It seems I'm back to original Q: if only suggests, why is it upgraded?

Comment: Although you answered that by "poppler-utils has a strong dependency on the same version of libpoppler", correct? Though `aptitude why` does not show that. Any "automated" way to see?

Comment: `apt show poppler-utils` shows the strong dependency with a specific version.

Comment: Took me longer to understand its applicability. Any way to see it automated way? `aptitude why` does not show that.

Comment: See the updated answer.